# How to get stats of the website's who use my web widget which has an iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, widget, tracking

I've deployed a web widget which basically has an iframe & an external Javascript.

I added GA to the iframe before deploying it hoping to analyse where my widget is used. However now I get stats of my widget from GA like the number of times the iframe is loaded & other traffic related things but not what I needed.

What I needed was the urls of the websites where my widget is embeded.

How can I do this? 
If GA not helps for this, Is there any other way to track my widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load an iframe, the initial 'referrer' value of the iframe will always be the value the page the iframe is contained on. (The exception is if the parent page is on HTTPS, and your iframe is in HTTP, then the referral value is blank, or if the site intentionally spoofs the referrer by POSTing into the iframe, like Facebook does for iframes on Fan pages).

So, if the parent URL is the referrer, that means to Google Analytics, the parent page is the Traffic Source. So, dig deep into your Traffic Sources report. The containing domain will be under `Source` (`example.com`), and the path of the URL will be under `Content` in the secondary dimension (`/path-to-page-with-your-iframe-on-it.html`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, you are right! I could find the containing domains under Traffic Source menu of Google Analytics. Thanks!